# $Hom(V,W)$ remains unchanged when norms of $V$ and $W$ are replaced with equivalent norms.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I was thinking about the following question from section 3.4 of Loomis and Sternberg's *Advanced Calculus*

> The fact that $Hom(V,W)$ is unchanged when norms are replaced by equivalent norms can be viewed as a corollary of Theorem 3.3. Show that this is so.

Here we are taking $V$ and $W$ to be normed real vector spaces and $Hom(V,W)$ to be the space of bounded linear maps between them. The theorem referenced in the question is the following:

*Given normed vector spaces $U,V,$ and $W$. Also, if $T \in Hom(U,V)$ and $S \in Hom(V,W)$ then $S \circ T \in Hom(U,W)$ and $\|S \circ T \| \leq \|S\| \|T \|$.*

I'll denote a vector space $V$ with norm $p: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as the pair $(V, p)$. I understand that if we have that if  $p_{1}, p_{2}$ are equivalent norms on $V$ and $q_{1}, q_{2}$ are equivalent norms on $W$, then I believe that the question is asking us to show that $T \in Hom( (V,p_{1}), (W,q_{1}))$ implies that $T \in Hom((V, p_{2}), (W, q_{2}))$.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Comment: The equivalence of norms means the identity operator is bounded (in either direction). The intended way is thus to compose $T$ with the identity operators on the domain and codomain. It is even less work if you think in topology, equivalent norms means the same topology, for normed spaces and linear maps, bounded means continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It helped a great deal. I wrote an answer below filling in the details and for practice. Thanks again.

Comment: The notation $Hom(V,W)$ for the set of *morphisms* of the category of normed linear spaces and continuous linear mappings is not appropriate: This is NOT an abelian categroy. Here, *homomorphisms* are continuous linear maps $T:V\to W$ with closed range such that $T:X\to Range(T)$ is open. (This is, of course, not the fault of the OP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer just fills in a few details in Daniel Fischer's comment above. I felt maybe writing an answer would be helpful and good practice.

The book states that two norms $p,q: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are equivalent is there exists scalars $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$  where for any $\xi \in V$, we have

- $p(\xi) \leq aq(\xi)$
- $q(\xi) \leq bp(\xi)$

This is the same as saying there exists constants $c_{1}, c_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ where $c_{1}q(\xi) \leq p(\xi) \leq c_{2}p(\xi)$. $\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}$

A linear map $T: V \rightarrow W$ is bounded when there exists a constant $c$, where for any vector $\xi \in V$, we have $\|T(\xi) \|_{W} \leq c\|\xi \|_{V}$. Now suppose that that we have two norms $p$ and $q$ on $V$ and the identity operator $\id:(V,p) \rightarrow (V,q)$ is bounded. This means that for any $\xi \in  V$, we have a $c \in \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ where $q(\id(\xi)) \leq c p(\xi)$. Also if the operator $\id:(V,q) \rightarrow (V,p)$ is bounded, there is a $c'$ where for any $\xi \in  V$, we have  $p(\id(\xi)) \leq c' q(\xi)$. This says exactly that the $p,q$ are equivalent norms.

My question above was trying to show $T \in Hom((V,p_{1}), (W,q_{1})$ implies $T \in Hom((V, p_{2}), (W,q_{2})$ using the theorem above. We can view $T$ as an element of $Hom((V, p_{2}), (W,q_{2}))$ in the following manner:

$$(V,p_{2}) \xrightarrow{\id} (V,p_{1}) \xrightarrow{T} (W, q_{1}) \xrightarrow{\id} (W, q_{2})$$

The theorem then states that $T \in Hom((V, p_{2}), (W,q_{2}))$.

Comment: In the third paragraph, you have mixed things up. You write that $p$ and $q$ are norms on the same space ($V$), so the inequality $q(T(\xi)) \leq cp(\xi)$ doesn't make sense, since $T(\xi) \in W$. I'm not sure whether you wanted $q(\xi) \leq cp(\xi)$ there - but that is already in the previous paragraph - or that $\lVert T(\xi)\rVert_W \leq c_p p(\xi)$ thus implies $\lVert T(\xi)\rVert_W \leq c_p\cdot c q(\xi)$. Also, in the first sentence of the paragraph, "there exists a constant $c$" must come before "for any vector $\xi$".

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think I meant to put $id$ instead of $T$. I made the changes above, I also fixed the order of the quantifiers,  I was confused about that.

Comment: Yup, it's fine now.